# Протестировать ViewModel с RxJava debounce

Tags: android, юнит-тесты, mockito

Для примера создал примерный код который нужно протестировать

```
class MyViewModel() : BaseViewModel() {

    private val valueSubject = BehaviorSubject.create<String>()

    private val viewState = MutableLiveData<State>()
    fun getViewState(): LiveData<State> = viewState

    init {
        disposables.add(valueSubject
                .debounce(150L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) //проблема
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe {
                    viewState.value = State(it)
                })
    }

    fun valueChanged(value: String) {
        viewState.value = State(value + " processing")
        valueSubject.onNext(value)
    }
}
```

Например, нужно написать текст который бы при `valueChanged("12")` отловил 2 изменения `viewState`, 1ое изменение это `viewState.value = State(value + " processing")`, а второе уже в подписке `valueSubject`.

Проблема как я понял тут в `debounce(150L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`, есть такие [примеры](https://medium.com/@grzesiek.matyszczak/how-to-test-debounce-in-rxjava-2-d43f64b5d58a) решения, но можно ли как то без прокидывания шедуллера?

Базовая часть теста

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class Test {

    @get:Rule
    var rule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
        RxJavaPlugins.onComputationScheduler(Schedulers.trampoline())
        RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
        RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
    }
    
}
```